# Как объединить несколько объектов в один массив

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как объединить несколько объектов в один массив?

```
res=[]
VK.api('groups.search', search_params, function (data) {
    if (data.response) {
        $.each(data.response,function(i,e){
            if(typeof(e)=="object"){
                res.push(e);
            }
            console.log(data) // object1{},object2{},object3{} и тд
        })
    }
```

Comment: `Object.assign` вам в помощь. Либо `Array.prototype.push`

Comment: `res=[]`; //....

Comment: неск. объектов в один объект, или в один массив с объектами?

Comment: в массив.,поправлю в теме

Comment: @G_test_00, у вас очипятка в коде. Не `res={}`, а `res=[]`

Comment: Какой тип у пула, где хранятся объекты? Ещё один объект или массив?

Comment: @Other e у меня там  объект

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = {
  response: {
    body: 1
  },
  1: 'string', // Судя по проверке в Вашем коде, в data не только объекты
  headers: {
    status: 200
  },
};

let result = [];
// Берём ключи объекта в массив (Object.keys), проходим по ним (Array.prototype.forEach)
// и проверяем каждое значение по ключу; сохраняем (Array.prototype.push)
// если значение является объектом
Object.keys(data).forEach(e => typeof data[e] === 'object' ? result.push(data[e]) : null);
console.info(result);
```